React Native's Flatlist Performance is very good in IOS simulators and devices, but scrooling slow in some Android devices and Simulators
I've tried many, many times installing React Native's App in IOS and Android devices and simulators. In IOS, flatlist performance is very good in all devices and simulators that I've tried to run. But in Android, it works smoothly only in some devices and simulators. I've noticed that flatlist strangely runs smoothly in older devices and Android versions, but it runs slowly and buggy in newer devices and simulators. How? Did anyone face this and found a clue? I've tried other libraries, like Flashlist, with no luck at all. I wish a good customer experience, and this Android instable behavior can't be called professional. I want flatlist to run smoothly on all devices, not only in the "lucky" ones Android owners, and Iphone users (IOS). Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!
I've tried everything. Installing, reinstalling, using alternative libraries, Googling, StackOverflowling, ChatGPT, etc, no luck at all.

I've done some research in react native's flatlist on Android, and I discovered that the problem only happens when the flatlist load images. I little bit more research and I realized that the problem was with images with BIG DIMENSIONS. So, all I had to do was to REDUCE THE DIMENSIONS OF THE PITURES. Now flatlist loads quickly, just as in IOS devices and simulators. Hope this can help someone.
